# Floating list issue

Tags: html, css

I am creating a list with 5 star rating. I want to put stars in from of list title but my stars are not showing in front of list title.

```css
.cont {
  color: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
hr {
  margin: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: thin solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}
div.stars {
  width: 270px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
input.star {
  display: none;
}
label.star {
  color: #444;
  float: right;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: all .2s;
}
input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
  content: '\f005';
  color: #FD4;
  transition: all .25s;
}
input.star-5:checked ~ label.star:before {
  color: #FE7;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}
input.star-1:checked ~ label.star:before {
  color: #F62;
}
label.star:hover {
  transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3);
}
label.star:before {
  content: '\f006';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
/* LIST #3 */

#list3 {
  float: left;
}
#list3 ul {
  list-style-image: url("../images/arrow.png");
  color: #4B4B4B;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
#list3 ul li {
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="list3">
  <ul>
    <li>Estimated time: 43min</li>
    <li>Distance in miles: 14 miles</li>
    <li>Review Rating:
      <div class="cont">
        <div class="stars">
          <form action="">
            <input class="star star-5" id="star-5-2" type="radio" name="star" />
            <label class="star star-5" for="star-5-2"></label>
            <input class="star star-4" id="star-4-2" type="radio" name="star" />
            <label class="star star-4" for="star-4-2"></label>
            <input class="star star-3" id="star-3-2" type="radio" name="star" />
            <label class="star star-3" for="star-3-2"></label>
            <input class="star star-2" id="star-2-2" type="radio" name="star" />
            <label class="star star-2" for="star-2-2"></label>
            <input class="star star-1" id="star-1-2" type="radio" name="star" />
            <label class="star star-1" for="star-1-2"></label>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://codepen.io/g1un/pen/KgvrwZ

```
.cont {
  color: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
/*   width: 100%; */

  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

div.stars {
/*   width: 270px; */
  display: inline-block;
/*   float: left; */
}
```

Your main mistake causing appearing of your rating icons below the title is that rating block has `display: block;` property by default as a `div` and you didn't change it.
It is also no need in `width: 100%` that causes element jumping to another row to fit this property.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. My problem is solved.

Comment: @Gilani you are wellcome!